# Unpacking nvidia-docker (1.0.1-1) over (1.0.1-1)

Tags: docker, nvidia, ubuntu-16.04

I follow the instruction from this site: https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker. to install nvidia-docker on the ubuntu 16.04 server. After running the command:

```
sudo dpkg -i /tmp/nvidia-docker*.deb && rm /tmp/nvidia-docker*.deb
```

there is error:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i /tmp/nvidia-docker*.deb && rm /tmp/nvidia-docker*.deb
(Reading database ... 479592 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../nvidia-docker_1.0.1-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-docker (1.0.1-1) over (1.0.1-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nvidia-docker:
nvidia-docker depends on docker-engine (>= 1.9.0) | docker-ce | docker-ee; however:
Package docker-engine is not installed.
Package docker-ce is not installed.
Package docker-ee is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package nvidia-docker (--install):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
nvidia-docker 


$ sudo service docker status
^[[0;1;31m●^[[0m docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: ^[[0;1;31mfailed^[[0m (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2017-04-18 10:05:27 JST; 35s ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
  Process: 18109 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// ^[[0;1;31m(code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)^[[0m
 Main PID: 18109 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Apr 18 10:05:27 NVIDIA2.cs179idcfcloud.internal systemd[1]: Starting Docker Application Container Engine...
Apr 18 10:05:27 NVIDIA2.cs179idcfcloud.internal dockerd[18109]: Error starting daemon: pid file found, ensure docker is not running or delete
/var/run/docker.pid
Apr 18 10:05:27 NVIDIA2.cs179idcfcloud.internal systemd[1]: ^[[0;1;39mdocker.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE^[[0m
Apr 18 10:05:27 NVIDIA2.cs179idcfcloud.internal systemd[1]: ^[[0;1;31mFailed to start Docker Application Container Engine.^[[0m
Apr 18 10:05:27 NVIDIA2.cs179idcfcloud.internal systemd[1]: ^[[0;1;39mdocker.service: Unit entered failed state.^[[0m
Apr 18 10:05:27 NVIDIA2.cs179idcfcloud.internal systemd[1]: ^[[0;1;39mdocker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.^[[0m


~$ sudo service docker start
Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

how to solve it?

Comment: Did you installed Docker (and the Ndivia drivers)?

Comment: hi thanks @ Railslide for your comments, I think I have installed it. Do you know how to confirm the information of docker and Ndivia information with command (ubuntu), thanks!

Comment: The error message suggests otherwise. Run `docker` and see if you get the help messages or an error

Comment: hi @Railslide thanks! for your comments. After I run the docker, there is just the docker command instruction, and no other information!

Comment: Check if the daemon is running `sudo service docker status`. If not, start it with `sudo service docker start`

Comment: thanks @Railslide, I have updated my questions contents, please check it. There are still errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it. Firstly restart the ubuntu server with linux command(sudo shutdown -r now), and run the command : apt-get -f install(this command is suggested by the error information), then I install the docker-engine by the following site(https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-docker-on-ubuntu-16-04). then install nvidia-docker, it works!